# How to customise SiriKit intent extension for shortcuts app to ask allow access?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts, intents-extension

We are allowed to build custom intent for Siri, by extending [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit). 
Moreover, Apples present how to manage basic integrations and customizations to [Siri Shortcuts and Shortcuts app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app)

[Link for shortcuts app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shortcuts/id915249334)

Nonetheless, some apps have their own shortcuts UI with a little customization; for instance with the button to allow access for API, how can we do that?

In the documentation presented by Apple, there is no such instruction for how is it possible to customize the UI inside the shortcuts app regarding the custom intent created by my app.

I tried to make custom failure for the Intent response but didn't find the option for API access. Like ↴

[image]

However nothing quite similar to the UI presented by Shortcuts App, while attempt to first run trello ↴

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These actions are provided by the Shortcuts app itself rather than by Siri intents exposed by another app. Indeed, these actions don’t even need the Trello or Wunderlist apps installed.

This means that Shortcuts can present a different UI.

The UI that it will show for your app is defined by the parameters in your intents file.

You can’t create the same experience for your app, however the user can perform any required authorisation in your app itself and it is reasonable to expect that they have run your app before trying to set up shortcuts that use it.

Comment: So, it is not possible to reproduce the same experience as the shortcuts for trello or wunderlist? those shortcuts weren't created by those apps? 
is not possible to ask the user to log into their accounts so we can perform some action?

Comment: I just search a bunch of apps that I don't have installed on my mobile, and they appeared as options for actions on shortcuts app. How does make it possible? How can I provide some action for my app?

Comment: Any actions that appear without having the app installed are built in to Shortcuts.  Apple acquired shortcuts from a company they purchased. That app has a bunch of functionality built in, which is what you are seeing

Comment: I created another question regarding the how to create a public action for shortcuts app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054290/how-to-provide-some-action-to-siri-shortcuts-app