# How to provide some action to Siri shortcuts app?

Tags: ios, siri, sirishortcuts

From that question [How to customise SiriKit intent extension for shortcuts app to ask allow access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053787/how-to-customise-sirikit-intent-extension-for-shortcuts-app-to-ask-allow-access)

I found out that some actions (for well-known apps) are provided by shortcuts app itself, so how can I provide for **shortcuts app** my own actions to my web service? How can I publish some web service action to my app for shortcuts library actions?

Comment: You would have to convince Apple to include such functionality in the Shortcuts app - The Shortcuts app does have the in-built ability to fetch data from a URL and you can specify the headers; If this isn't easy enough then you could create an app that exposed your API via SiriKit Intents.